# conditional based searching using regex

Tags: regex

I am try to search a list of elements that are related to a particular flavor of linux adn the default, but never for different flavor.

eg: I have 3 items to be searched:

```
driver.rhel7.x86_64.rpm
driver.rhel6.x86_64.rpm
driver.linux.x86_64.rpm
driver.xxxxx.x86_64.rpm
```

The condition is: if you find rhel6 take it, if linux take it and everything else, but never rhel7.

I am trying something like the following look ahead regular expression, but it does not work.

rhel(?=6)?|.x86_64.rpm

but this is matching rhel7 also.

Comment: Why not just search for `driver\.(rhel6|linux)\.x86_64\.rpm`

Comment: I want something like this - If you find rhel make sure it is rhel6 but never rhel7 and take match everything else.

Comment: you mean this http://regex101.com/r/nG1gU7/22 ?

Comment: @Avinash : The negative condition could be anything not just rhel7, it could be rhel8 or 9 or 9u1 or anything.

Comment: sorry, it's so hard to understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If rhel it must be rhel6, otherwise anything:

```
driver\.(?!rhel([^6]|\d\d)).*?\.x86_64\.rpm
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/X94S1ojSCS)

Comment: Not just this condition, I would like to match everything else as there could be lot of things added to the list in future. If you find rhel match the version else take everything else.

Comment: @Vinay i see, so it's anything other than "rhel7" - try the edit

Comment: It is like this - if a driver for a particular rhel version is available match the version and take that particular driver, in case the driver for a particular version is not available use the default linux but never use a driver of a different version of rhel like 7 or 8 or anything else. Hope I am clear.

Comment: @Vinay OK - I think I've got it. Interesting - I've never used a negative character class in a negative look ahead before.

Comment: What if the text is: `driver.rhel67.x86_64.rpm`?

Comment: @ridgerunner OK, good point. Your extra edge case is now catered for too (and demo link updated to show it's working).

Answer (score 2):

Edited answer based on comments:

```
^(?:[^r]|r(?!hel7))*\.x86_64\.rpm
```

[Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/xK5sF6/2)

Looking at the use-case I'm guessing you want any drivers that end with text signifying that they're for rhel6 or linux, 64bit architecture and in an `rpm` package.

***Edit*** From the comments under my and other people's answers I'm deriving that you want the regex **not** to match the `linux` variant if a `rhel6` match was found before (or after)? This is logic outside of your regex. The regex is unaware of previous (or future) matches. So you should match anything that isn't `rhel7` and iterate through the driver-names up to the linux-flavor part. For each driver-name you see if a `rhel6` variant exists, if so take it, if not, search for a linux variant.

I don't know what environment you're working with but presumably Bash should be able to do something like that yes? Or Python or something. This is a case of *"Regex is your tool, not your solution."* **:)**

Comment: This solves for this particular condition. How about this. If you find rhel search for version 6, if not give me everything but never rhel 7?

Comment: Edited answer for more precise conditions, regex101 link opdated also.

Comment: This looks very good. Can you please let me know how I can match the positive condition. I have information of only the position value say rhel6, but the negative could be anything like rhel7, rhel7u3, rhel6u1. So, I don't know the negative value you mentioned in the regex above "hel7". Otherwise this works!

Comment: I am looking at find me drivers for a particular version if you find it but never for other versions, if no driver is found for a particular version use the linux default.

Comment: Edited my answer explaining why you need more than just 1 regex ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
driver\.(?!rhel7).*
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/nG1gU7/21